# Is there possibility to put a lock after a method?

Tags: java

I am creating tictactoe game and I wanted to create a loop(below). Player can be human or computer. Now I would like to make code wait until a statement inside  method `player.move()`  will  UNLOCK. How to achieve that?

```
while(!finished){
 Player player = fetchNextPlayer();
 player.move();//MOVE suppose to encourage human player to click on a certain JButton
 LOCK;//until there is a line in move() saying to unlock.
}
```

The deal is that move() in case of `Player` should just encourage player to click on a button and if `fetchNextPlayer()` returns instance of `ComputerPlayer extends Player` it suppose to automatically click a certain button. If there will be no lock the `ComputerPlayer` will not wait until human player clicks the button.

Comment: Unless you're multithreading, just don't return from `move` until you're ready. That should do the same thing.

Comment: @AndrewMedico The deal is that move() in case of `Player` should just encourage player to click on a button and if `fetchNextPlayer()` returns instance of `ComputerPlayer extends Player` it suppose to automatically click a certain button.

Comment: This whole approach seems suspect to me. If you're writing a GUI, you usually can't really sensibly "wait until a button is pressed", and should think in terms of an event stream driving everything.

Comment: @millimoose You are probably right. I try that tomorrow(2am here), thanks.

Comment: I would probably use a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) to "remind" the user through the UI to click a button. If the user does click a button you can call `cancel()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Could you post a small snippet of what you have in mind?